# What is the reason for GERTY having that name?

Tags: moon-movie

I've done some [Googling](https://www.google.com/#q=gerty+moon+acronym) but been unable to find out much about GERTY's name. My questions are:

1. What does GERTY stand for (assuming it is an acronym)?
2. (If, as it seems, GERTY does not stand for anything) where does the name come from?

Comment: *A state of the art robot, a GERTY 3000 -- known simply as “GERTY” -- is preparing Sam’s breakfast.* - [Screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/scripts/moon-2009.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The AI in the station was a "GERTY 3000L ROBOTIC ASSIST" as you can see in the screenshot below.  The parallels with HAL from *2001: A Space Odyssey* are pretty obvious.

[image: front of GERTY]

Comment: Sure, there are parallels with the HAL9000. But I don't think this answers my question about GERTY's *name*.

Comment: The spacing around the name in this picture suggests that it originally may be longer, like `QWERTY`